# Get Elastic Search Results with least difference between two Stringified lists

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard-mapping

I have one of the field indexed as String of list of strings
eg> "["string1", "string2","string3","string4","string5"]"

In that column I have values:

1. "["string1", "string2","string3","string4","string5"]"
2. "["string1", "string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7"]"

on this columns, lets call it "testColumn", I will pass a input as "query": "["string1", "string2","string3","string4"*" (with wildcard) I want my results to be matched with the least difference with my input string.

so I want my first output "["string1", "string2","string3","string4","string5"]"
and then "["string1", "string2","string3","string4","string5","string6","string7"]"
because my query string matches both the records but, the difference between the length of both string is less in first record.

I have tried using the wildcard but didn't work.

```
"wildcard":{
       "testColumn": {
              "boost": 0.0,
              "value":"[\"string1\", \"string2\",\"string3\",\"string4\"*"
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `script` to sort the matches by length?

```
"sort": {
   "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "order": "desc",
      "script": {
         "lang": "painless",
         "source": "doc['testColumn'].value.length()"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I made some changes though in the structure. I indexed the list